# Docker Compose compiles successfully, and from within the container its returning the webpage successfully using curl but not from host

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose

Im building out a docker dev environment and moving a bunch of existing apps into docker containers.

I have a an old react app which compiles using webpack, it seems no matter what I do in the docker compose file that it still remains unreachable from my host machine (MacOS)

running this works successfully, but not from the host

```
$ docker exec -it <container id> /bin/sh
# curl localhost:8080
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  ...
</html>
```

##### Dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM node:16.16.0-buster as base

WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
COPY webpack.common.js ./
## import prod, because after install the build script tests if it can compile successfully
COPY webpack.prod.js ./
COPY . ./

RUN yarn install

EXPOSE 8080

FROM base as dev
CMD ["yarn", "run", "dev"]
```

###### Option 1) Doesnt Work

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  backbone-ui:
    network_mode: host
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: backbone-ui
    ports:
      - target: 8080
        host_ip: 127.0.0.1
        published: 8080
        protocol: http
        mode: host
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    command:  yarn run dev
```

###### Option 2) Doesnt Work

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  backbone-ui:
    network_mode: host
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: backbone-ui
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    command:  yarn run dev
```

###### Option 3) Doesnt Work

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  backbone-ui:
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: backbone-ui
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    command:  yarn run dev
```

---

###### Failed Attempt

###### Dockerfile (paired with Option 2 compose.yml)

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM node:16.16.0-buster as base

WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
COPY webpack.common.js ./
COPY webpack.prod.js ./
COPY . ./

RUN yarn install

FROM base as dev
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["yarn", "run", "dev"]
```

###### Failed Attempt

updated package.json script

```
"dev": "webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.dev.js --hot --host 0.0.0.0"
```

confirmed after rebuilding that the app is listening on 0.0.0.0:8080, but failed to respond on the host

```
$ docker exec -it <container id> /bin/sh
# curl 0.0.0.0:8080
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  ...
</html>
```

Comment: I think you simply need to move the EXPOSE line below the FROM line

Comment: doesnt work using option #1 compose file + the Dockerfile change suggested `docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml up --build`

Comment: yeah, you have to rebuild the image, since the dockerfile has changed. Try the suggested command with the third option

Comment: I would say the issue is that your app is listening on 127.0.0.1:8080 only, which is not enough for port mapping in docker. You need your react app to listen on 0.0.0.0:8080. Then the third option of compose file is the one to use.

Comment: `EXPOSE` line + rebuilt option #2 unfortunately didnt work  i'll try binding to 0.0.0.0, i have tried that before though, but will document the steps taken

Comment: updated details with the failed attempt using 0.0.0.0

Comment: I doubt it is the problem, but I don't think you need to specify `command` in your `docker-compose.yml` if you've already got the `CMD` in your Docker file.  Just to be clear, what is the exact command you are trying from the host?  And what does "*failed to respond on the host*" mean, *exactly*?  Does `docker logs` show anything interesting?

Comment: BTW `0.0.0.0` is not a real IP address, not intended for use like `curl 0.0.0.0`, it is more like a wildcard which represents "any IP address". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0

Comment: What I can see here is with your volume in the docker-compose override install all the dependencies

Comment: @Don'tPanic understood, it was late at night and i should have probably used `netstat` instead of a curl request to display what interfaces are actively listening.

Comment: @Don'tPanic - removing the command statement from my docker-compose.yml file solved!